# Detecting a specific CSS keyframe animation with JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have two CSS `@keyframe` animations applied to the same element. One that fires on `:hover` and the other that fires on mouse out, both applied with CSS.

I was curious to know if there was a way to detect the end of a selected keyframe animation rather than it being attached to the element and firing twice?

Comment: You can only detect when an animation ends, not a single keyframe.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude At first i understood question as you, but now i think OP just wants to detect just specific animation ends, not for each keyframe. So Harry's answer is correct

Comment: Both answers are fine in this case. The first answer is correct too. I upvote both of them

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude You mean Sumanta736's answer? Because no, it isn't correct, it would be fired only once unregarding animation is replayed.  I don't think it is expected behaviour here (i could be wrong of course...)

Comment: Bah, it's because the `one()` method instead of `on()` method, but the idea is the same and the result will be as OP expected. The better answer is from Harry, but the other I think is good too.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude but in other answer, no filtering is done regarding which animation completes. I really guess this is all the point of this question here: `One that fires on :hover and the other that fires on mouse out` **&** `detect the end of a selected keyframe animation rather than it being attached to the element and firing twice`

Comment: The question is very ambiguous and I can't understand fine what the hell he needs, but I am waiting for his explanation or his accepted answer. Well, we will see what happens!

Comment: For the fun (chrome only), if your question was to detect current running keyframe: https://jsfiddle.net/z4ytsesh/  And here using an animated property to get progress in percent https://jsfiddle.net/z4ytsesh/1/  I'm sure this is offtopic but...

Answer (score 9):

> if there was a way to detect the end of a selected keyframe animation

If your intention is to detect the ***ending of a keyframe animation*** itself instead of detect end of every keyframe then, yes, it can be done using the [`animationend` event](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animationend). This event is fired every time any animation that is attached to the element is completed and the context info has one parameter named `animationName` using which we can find which animation had ended.

The `animationName` parameter is important because when multiple animations would be applied to the same element like in your case then you'd need to know which animation had actually ended because this event would get fired at the end of every animation.

**Using vanilla JS:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.animate');
  var op = document.querySelector('.output');

  elm.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) { /* this is fired at end of animation */
    op.textcontent = 'Animation ' + e.animationName + ' has ended';
  });
  elm.addEventListener('animationstart', function(e) { /* this is fired at start of animation */
    op.textcontent = 'Animation ' + e.animationName + ' has started';
  });
}
```

```css
.animate {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: shake-up-down 2s ease;
}
.animate:hover {
  animation: shake-left-right 2s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes shake-up-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }  
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }  
}
@keyframes shake-left-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }  
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animate'></div>

<div class='output'></div>
```

---

**Using jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elm = $('.animate');
  var op = $('.output');

  elm.on('animationend', function(e) { /* fired at the end of animation */
    op.html('Animation ' + e.originalEvent.animationName + ' has ended');
  });
  elm.on('animationstart', function(e) { /* fired at the start of animation */
    op.html('Animation ' + e.originalEvent.animationName + ' has started');
  });  
});
```

```css
.animate {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: shake-up-down 2s ease;
}
.animate:hover {
  animation: shake-left-right 2s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes shake-up-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes shake-left-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animate'></div>

<div class='output'></div>
```

In the above snippet, you can see how the `.output` div's content indicates the name of the animation that is ended after each animation completes.

> **Note:** CSS animations still need vendor prefixes in some browsers/versions. To be on the safer side, you need to listen for the prefixed versions of the animationend event also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t,
  el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

 var animations = {
   "animation"      : "animationend",
   "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
   "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
   "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
 }

for (t in animations){
  if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
    return animations[t];
  }
 }
}

var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();

$(".button").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("animate");
$(this).one(animationEvent,
          function(event) {
  // Do something when the animation ends
 });
});
```